# pgfplots: How to get the correct height of a label, if fontsize has changed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

I set `font=\Huge` for a `ylabel`. 
With `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}` I get the label-text. 
But how to get the correct value while measuiring the height with 
`\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\yLabelHeight{height("\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}")}`? 
Is there a way to read that out with pgfkeys?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\section{Graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={yLabel Huge},
y label style={draw, font=\Huge,   },
xmin=0,
%clip=false
]
\addplot[]{x};
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\yLabelHeight{height("\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}")}
\node[anchor=south west, fill=yellow, font=\small] at (0,0) {
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel} has a height \yLabelHeight (wrong!)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsection{Normalsize}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\yLabelHeight{height("yLabel Huge")} 
"yLabel Huge" has a height \yLabelHeight
\subsection{Huge}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\yLabelHeight{height("\Huge yLabel Huge")} 
{\Huge "yLabel Huge"} has a height \yLabelHeight
\end{document}
```

Comment: How will you use `\yLabelHeight`?

Comment: Ok, good question. For a global use, if necessary,  I know, what I can do (`\pgfkeys{/tikz/savevalue/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}`). At this moment my main-problem is how to get the correct value.

Comment: There could be sth. with `.store in`. But I do not get it at this moment.

Comment: Why you think it is wrong? I think it is correct.

Comment: It is correct for \normalsize, not fot \Huge

Answer (score 1):

You can save the font style of the node (`\tikz@node@textfont` and `\tikz@textfont`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  savefont/.style={
    execute at begin node={%
      \begingroup%
      \toks\z@=\expandafter{\tikz@node@textfont}%
      \toks\@ne=\expandafter{\tikz@textfont}%
      \xdef#1{\the\toks\z@\the\toks\@ne}%
      \endgroup%
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\Huge, savefont=\myfont] {abd};
\node[font=\myfont] at (0, 2) {abd};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```